# Dynamic email in CF7 (using custom fields)

Tags: php, contact-form-7

I'm trying to dynamically update the CF7 to field by replacing the recipient string with a custom post field value, though I can't figure out how to assign the value it's definitely replacing the string as I get an error and if I change email it sends. So it tells me the problem is when I'm trying to get the value.

```
<?php
function wpcf7_dynamic_email_field($args) {
  $dynamic_email = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dynamic_email', true);
  if(!empty($args['recipient'])) {
    $args['recipient'] = str_replace('emailtobereplaced@email.com', $dynamic_email["dynamic_email"], $args['recipient']);
    return $args;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_components', 'wpcf7_dynamic_email_field');
?>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? My custom field is called dynamic_email and I need the value

Answer (score 3):

`get_the_id()` won't return the proper ID because Contact form 7 uses Ajax to perform the send.

You can get the post ID from the submission unit tag. The unit tag is a hidden form field that gets posted with the form and it looks cryptic but it stores information about the post. An example unit tag looks like `wpcf7-f235-p27-o1`. Using a regex we can get the post id out of the unit tag.

```
function wpcf7_dynamic_email_field( $args ) {

    $dynamic_email = '';
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $unit_tag = $submission->get_meta( 'unit_tag' );

    // get the post ID from the unit tag
    if ( $unit_tag && preg_match( '/^wpcf7-f(\d+)-p(\d+)-o(\d+)$/', $unit_tag, $matches ) ) {
        $post_id = absint( $matches[2] );
        $dynamic_email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'dynamic_email', true );
    }

    if ( $dynamic_email ) {
        $args['recipient'] = str_replace('emailtobereplaced@email.com', $dynamic_email["dynamic_email"], $args['recipient']);
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'wpcf7_dynamic_email_field' );
```

Since this is a filter and not an action you always want to return the first parameter that was passed to your callback in this case `$args`.

Comment: Thanks, this is some really useful info I didn't know. The contact form appears to be sending now however the email doesn't come through so I'm not sure if it's an error in the way I called my custom field? am I right that it should call the first email in this field?

Comment: Try changing `$dynamic_email["dynamic_email"]` to just `$dynamic_email` in your `str_replace` call

Comment: Yeah I tried that but to no avail. I tried changing `get_post_meta_values( $post_id, 'dynamic_email', true )` too but it didn't seem to send the email -- no worries. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Add `file_put_contents( get_template_directory() . '/debug.log', print_r( $dynamic_email, true ), FILE_APPEND );` after you retrieve the post meta value. Then check the debug.log in your template directory and see what the value of `$dynamic_email` is

Comment: Not sure if I've done it right but it's coming back blank

Comment: Are you sure you have set your custom field and that the name of the custom field is correct?

Comment: Hmm I think so, the table says name | value and the name is dynamic_email and value is set to an email address -- is this correct? Also when I say it's coming back blank I mean the whole .log is blank (it didn't create a file so I created it and ran it)

Comment: It should automatically be created. Are you using a child theme?

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't mention that - I am using a child theme

Comment: Oh okay. The debug.log will be in your parent theme. You can make it go to the child them by swapping `get_template_directory()` with `get_stylesheet_directory()`

Comment: Hmm still doesn't seem to give me anything (in parent or child directories) I'm really confused as to why, I have tried adding it after `$dynamic_email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'dynamic_email', true );`, `$args['recipient'] = str_replace('emailtobereplaced@email.com', $dynamic_email["dynamic_email"], $args['recipient']);` and also at the end after `return $args;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125034/discussion-between-jrod-and-stuart-pontins).

Comment: Sorry I fell asleep last night -- I'll wait in the chat in case you come back at some point today. Thanks for all of your help so far.